# Actionbar color not changing in android (Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Actionbar color not changing in android (Lollipop), here is my styles.xml code

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">#EBE1CE</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following style

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryDef</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkDef</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primaryDef</item>

        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primaryDarkDef</item>
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/defbg</item>
    </style>
```

The Action Bar will be colored by `colorPrimary`

Comment: This fixed my problem as well. Why does the old way not work and this does?

Answer (score 2):

The below code works fine for me:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Widget.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">     
        <item name="height">100dp</item>
        <item name="background">#EBE1CE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```